# Reference request: moduli spaces of vector bundles

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, vector-bundles, complex-geometry, reference-request, moduli-spaces

I am trying to study the moduli spaces of holomorphic vector bundles quickly, and I'm primarily interested in understanding:

1. Why and where the stability condition is used.
2. How are the moduli spaces constructed.
3. What are the examples, especially in the case of vector bundles on curves.

I was looking for some references but I could not find any reasonable source online.
I have the base for that and I don't want some thing very long and full of details.

I just want to see all the ideas very clearly without to much details.

Please tell me if you know any lecture notes or a book which contains this stuff.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Did you look at the question http://mathoverflow.net/questions/44125/what-is-a-good-introductory-text-for-moduli-theory ?

Comment: Yes, that question is some how general, I know many moduli theories. I'm looking for a source for this specific moduli theory. 

Comment: I don't know about online refs, but there are plenty of books by
Huybrechts-Lehn, Le Potier, Mukai, Seshadri...
In a nutshell, stability is what is needed to get GIT methods to work.

Comment: Mumford's GIT. He explains the construction of many moduli spaces including vector bundles from a single point of view. If you know the theory of moduli of Riemann surfaces he explains vector bundles in the same language.

Answer (score 13):

Dear Mohammad, there is a rather elementary book  *Introduction to Moduli Problems and Orbit spaces* by P.E. Newstead which will explain to you  why stability is important, give you lots of examples (Chapter 4 is devoted to them) and which ends with a whole chapter (Chapter 5) called *Vector bundles over a curve*. It was written by an extremely  competent expert and deliberately maintained at a quite elementary level. The author explains in the preface that his notes are an introduction to Mumford's Geometric Invariant Theory in the language of classical algebraic geometry, deliberately eschewing schemes.

On the subject of holomorphic bundles over $\mathbb P^n(\mathbb C) $ you may check Okonek, Schneider and Spindler's monograph *Vector Bundles on Complex Projective Spaces*, written in the language of holomorphic manofolds (the results are the same as in algebraic geometry thanks to Serre's GAGA principle).

I'd also like to mention Atiyah's classic *Vector bundles over an elliptic curve*
published in 1957,  which I still find quite instructive despite its venerable age.

And finally I should also mention the articles on moduli of vector bundles over curves written by the brilliant Indian school around the Tata Institute: M.S.Narasimhan, Seshadri, Ramanan, Nori, ...

Answer (score 2):

Twelve years after Atiyah's article classifying vector bundles on curves of genus one, Narasimhan and Ramanan published a lovely paper in the Annals, (89) no.2, 1969, p.14, where they solved the case of semi stable rank 2 vector bundles on genus two curves.  This case is perhaps more typical of the higher genus situation.  Basically, a rank two vector bundle is analyzed by producing a sub line bundle, whose quotient is also a line bundle, and then studying how the vector bundle is reconstructed as a twisted sum of those two line bundles.  I cannot improve on the wonderful references given by Georges Elencwajg above, but I have a short 4 or 5 page set of notes from a lecture given by Daniele Arcara, in a graduate class of mine, summarizing the status of moduli of rank 2 bundles on curves in 2001, if there is some way to send it to you or attach it here as a pdf file....

I sent them to your email address at Princeton.

Comment: Just googling "vector bundles on curves" already yields some interesting results.  The first hit for me was a set of notes by Teixidor (http://www.tufts.edu/~mteixido/files/vectbund.pdf) classifying bundles on curves of genera zero and one,

and the 4th hit was a nice article by Beauville, Vector bundles on curves and theta functions, surveying results on the natural theta maps from moduli of vector bundles to projective space.  
http://www.google.com/#hl=en&expIds=17259,18167,27100,27102,27137,27640,27658&sugexp=ldymls&xhr=t&q=vector+bundles+on+curves&cp=20&qe=dmVjdG9yIGJ1bmRsZXMgb24gY3U&qe

