# Geometric invariant theory for geometers

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, cv.complex-variables, dg.differential-geometry, gt.geometric-topology, sg.symplectic-geometry

I am trying to learn "Geometric invariant theory" like it was introduced by Mumford. But I do not have a strong background in algebraic geometry since I work in geometric topology and geometry.

So my question is if there is any nice reference where people explain geometric invariant theory from a geometric viewpoint. In particular, I am looking for a good reference where the analogies between algebraic geometry and differential geometry are pointed out.

Comment: Algebraic geometry is not geometry?

Comment: @ Angelo: As I tried to make precise I mean differential geometry or geometric topology by the notion geometry.

Comment: Maybe Richard Thomas' "Notes on GIT and symplectic reduction for bundles and varieties" [ http://arxiv.org/abs/math.AG/0512411 ] ? 

Comment: Chapter 1 of this thesis http://arxiv.org/abs/math/0611002 is also very useful.

Comment: I think these kinds of questions are a bit silly; imagine asking about a reference for elliptic operators that doesn't use any theory of Sobolev spaces!  At the very least, I think the OP should clarify more carefully what is his background in (presumably complex) differential geometry, and precisely how far along he is in learning algebraic geometry.

Comment: you might consult answets to this question"

http://mathoverflow.net/questions/44125/what-is-a-good-introductory-text-for-moduli-theory

Answer (score 7):

If you just want to get a feeling for invariant theory, here are some books that aren't necessarily comprehensive but nevertheless are enlightening at a more leisurely pace as compared to GIT, which would be useful for someone who isn't as familiar with algebraic groups and algebraic geometry:

- Santos and Rittatore - Actions and Invariants of Algebraic Groups: Minimal prerequisites. A very gentle introduction to some aspects of invariant theory, including some motivation via Hilbert's 14th problem. This book also contains most of the required theory of linear algebraic groups.
- Dolgachev - Lectures on Invariant Theory: This takes a more geometric viewpoint and might be something you are interested in. This only requires some basic knowledge of algebraic geometry.
- Schmitt - Geometric Invariant Theory and Decorated Principal Bundles: this might also be interesting if you are interested in the geometric applications and the related geometry, though I haven't looked into this book very much, but Part 1 does contain a fairly leisurely-looking introduction to GIT

There is also Popov's and Vinberg's treatise "Invariant Theory" in the Ecyclopedia of Mathematical Sciences Volume 55 (Springer) which contains a good summary of the classical results in characteristic zero.

Answer (score 5):

I would recommend a look at chapter 8 of the **third** edition of *Geometric invariant theory* by Mumford, Forgarty and Kirwan.  It describes a connection between GIT and Hamiltonian group actions in symplectic geometry.

(edit) You may also like [Moment maps and geometric invariant theory](http://arxiv.org/abs/0912.1132) by Chris Woodward.

Comment: Hi Eugene, nice to see you here.

Comment: The longer version being Kirwan's thesis, published as "Cohomology of Quotients in Symplectic and Algebraic Geometry".

Answer (score 2):

For a "more classical" point of view:

"An introduction to Invariants and Moduli " by S. Mukai.

Fogarty J. "Invariant theory" (Benjamin, 1969)

For a introduction to Mumford's:

P. E. Newstead, "Introduction to Moduli Problems and Orbit Spaces"

Anyway you have to learn (before or after) a Gothendieck-categorical background:

Fondements de la géométrie algébrique (Grothendick).
The Hilbert schema chapter is very important (need the Hartshorne "Algebraic Geometry" as base)

Or in more gentle way: 
Fundamental Algebraic Geometry. Grothendieck's FGA Explained  - Fantechi B., Göttsche, L., Illusie L.

Comment: Typo correction: "Mukay" --> "Mukai".

Comment: Typo correction: "Moduly" --> "Moduli". (Sorry could not resist. :) )

Answer (score 2):

Read the survey in my [article](https://arxiv.org/abs/math/0611771) and go over the references therein. It is written with exactly similar intentions you have asked for.

*Kalafat, Mustafa*, [**Geometric invariant theory and Einstein-Weyl geometry**](http://dx.doi.org/10.1016/j.exmath.2011.01.002), Expo. Math. 29, No. 2, 220-230 (2011); addendum ibid. 37, No. 1, 92-95 (2019). [ZBL1250.14034](https://zbmath.org/?q=an:1250.14034), [MR2787619](https://mathscinet.ams.org/mathscinet-getitem?mr=2787619).